# IOS swift - How can I end the editing in textfield after opening a new view controller when textfield is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

hello I have a text field on my view controller. I am launching another view controller when user taps or click in the textfield. It is working successfully but the problem is when I press the back button from second view controller, It shows first controller and immediately  it again redirect me to the 2nd view controller. screen doesn't stays on 1st controller. it is because cursor is there on the textfield so thats why.I don't no how can I make text field inactive after I move to the 2nd controller. hope you understand my question.

here is the code I am using

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

          self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true)
        //delegate method
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

return false in the given method, it means your keyboard will not show and you will directly redirect to your 2nd viewcontroller.

```
          func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

          self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true)
        //delegate method
        return false // Change here return false it means it won't show keyboard
    }
```

Comment: @ Mukesh Chaudhary No I recently visited dubai. I am from pakistan why ?

Comment: @ Mukesh Chaudhary okay navigation bar comes up but now back button isn't working now

Comment: @hellosheikh i told you earlier you need to customise back button and please response on comment of last question

Comment: @ Mukesh Chaudhary  sorry what customization should I do ? could you please guide me.. I am new in IOS

Comment: @hellosheikh Could i help you later evening?

Comment: okay I'll wait thank you.. did you get my skype ??? also I don't think so its the same animation like the gif